# How to deploy MERN stack app on AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mern

I am trying to deploy my MERN stack app on AWS by using elastic beanstalk but I could not find any good tutorial that can help me through it.

My app structure is like below.

[image]

`root level package.json`

```
  ....,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seeder",
    "data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d",
  },
  ....,
```

`package.json inside /frontend`

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

1. Do I need to setup aws code pipeline to build frontend, backend servers ? If yes which commands should I use ?
2. I do have .env for backend server parameters, how should I set environment variables on aws elastic beanstalk ?

Comment: EBS is better suited with docker and github actions

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Comment: @bogdanoff I used (ECS) Amazon Elastic Container Service's AWS Fargate
[1] https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/ 
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/what-is-fargate.html